# input type in android such keypad first line of keyboard show numeric and then qwety keyboard

Tags: android

In android i want a keyboard which has first row with all the numeric and then QWERTY Keyboard show with in same keypad so is it possible in android 
                    samsung phone show keyboard like this
                         How Write in XML as well as programmatically

Answer (score -2, accepted):

use code `editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_QWERTY);`

Comment: this doesn't work for me, I am getting numeric keyboard instead